# How do I get Kissmetrics installed properly on a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, chef-infra, kissmetrics

I am using the Ruby API method of getting the KM API installed, but I am not sure if I'm doing it properly. The first thing I did is put the KM init code in my init.rb file:

```
KM.init("API-KEY", 
  :log_dir => '/var/logs/km/', 
  :use_cron => true, 
  :to_stderr => true)
```

I replaced API-KEY with my api key, obviously. It then says that the proper way of doing it is to save the data in a file and send it to KM every 5 minutes as a cronjob. My first question is - is /var/logs/km/ the right directory to save the data in? I don't actually see that directory in my rails app.

I then am using a chef recipe to send the cron jobs as follows:

```
# send KM logs to KM
cron "Send KM data to KM" do
  minute  '*/5'
  hour    '*'
  day     '*'
  month   '*'
  weekday '*'
  command "/usr/bin/ruby /km-install-dir/bin/km_send"
end
```

I'm also not sure if this is correct. The example shows the cron code as follows:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/ruby /km-install-dir/bin/km_send
```

Which is how I made the cron job in chef. So, few questions: how do I know if it's working or not? I can't seem to find the file where the data is stored for the cron job, did I put it in the wrong directory? Is my chef recipe correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use Chef to send the data asynchronously.
You can install the [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debuggerShare) gem and check if the KM variable is initialized in the right environment (development.rb, production.rb). Also check if the log directory has the right privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the KissMetrics data to a file and setting up a cron job, I've had good results combining [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with [delayed_km](https://github.com/vbrendel/delayed_km).

The event data is saved in the database and then sent in batches at regular intervals.
I found this removed the need to setup custom cron jobs and potentially makes it easier to scale your app. KissMetrics has a [small amount of documentation](http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/ruby/heroku) on this.